# query works in workbench but not in mysql client

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this that works in MySQL workbench:

```
mysql> select concat('insert into SE_POPN (POPN_ID,RQST_ID,LOB_CD,POPN_NM,INSRT_DT,INSRT_USER_ID,UPD_DT,UPD_USER_ID) 
values ("',case when POPN_ID is null then '' else POPN_ID end,'","',
case when RQST_ID is null then '' else RQST_ID end,'","',
case when LOB_CD is null then '' else LOB_CD end,'","',
case when POPN_NM is null then '' else POPN_NM end,'","',
case when INSRT_DT is null then '' else INSRT_DT end,'","',
case when INSRT_USER_ID is null then '' else INSRT_USER_ID end,'","',
case when UPD_DT is null then '' else UPD_DT end,'","',
case when UPD_USER_ID is null then '' else UPD_USER_ID end,'");') 
from se_popn;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1

But, it doesn't work in the MySQL client. I keep getting a syntax error.

Comment: What is the syntax error you're getting?

Comment: Please format your query so it is human readable.

Comment: Please show how you're trying to execute the query in your client. I suspect the problem is with quoting -- you need to escape the quotes inside the query that match the quotes you're using in the client code.

Comment: just made an edit...I use mysql client to run it....and also posted the error I get. I think you're right about escaping the quotes but how do I escape them? I tried `\"` but got the same results...

Comment: @Barmar, you are right...just need `\"` instead of `"`

Comment: You still haven't posted how you're trying to run it with the client.

Answer (score 0):

You may be just missing a semi-colon(`;`) at the end.

> A command need not be given all on a single line, so lengthy commands
>   that require several lines are not a problem. mysql determines where
>   your statement ends by looking for the terminating semicolon, not by
>   looking for the end of the input line. (In other words, mysql accepts
>   free-format input: it collects input lines but does not execute them
>   until it sees the semicolon.)
>   [Read more on dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html)

Try following code,

```
SELECT Concat( 
'insert into SE_POPN (POPN_ID,RQST_ID,LOB_CD,POPN_NM,INSRT_DT,INSRT_USER_ID,UPD_DT,UPD_USER_ID) values ("'
, CASE 
WHEN popn_id IS NULL THEN '' 
ELSE popn_id 
END, '","', CASE 
              WHEN rqst_id IS NULL THEN '' 
              ELSE rqst_id 
            END, '","', CASE 
                          WHEN lob_cd IS NULL THEN '' 
                          ELSE lob_cd 
                        END, '","', CASE 
                                      WHEN popn_nm IS NULL THEN '' 
                                      ELSE popn_nm 
                                    END, '","', CASE 
                                                  WHEN insrt_dt IS NULL THEN '' 
                                                  ELSE insrt_dt 
                                                END, '","', CASE 
                                                              WHEN insrt_user_id IS NULL THEN '' 
                                                              ELSE insrt_user_id 
                                                            END, '","', CASE 
                                                                          WHEN upd_dt IS NULL THEN '' 
                                                                          ELSE upd_dt 
                                                                        END, '","', CASE 
                                                                                      WHEN upd_user_id IS NULL THEN ''
                                                                                      ELSE upd_user_id
                                                                                    END, '");') 
FROM   se_popn;
```

I just rearranged a code and added a semi-colon(`;`) at the end.
It is working for me.

Comment: sorry...I am using a `;` at the end of the statement. I just made an edit to show how I run it in the client and the error I get...made my question a little more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid having to deal with quoting problems with the `mysql` client is to use a here-doc instead of `mysql -e`:

```
mysql <options> dbname <<EOF
select concat('insert into SE_POPN (POPN_ID,RQST_ID,LOB_CD,POPN_NM,INSRT_DT,INSRT_USER_ID,UPD_DT,UPD_USER_ID) 
values ("',case when POPN_ID is null then '' else POPN_ID end,'","',
case when RQST_ID is null then '' else RQST_ID end,'","',
case when LOB_CD is null then '' else LOB_CD end,'","',
case when POPN_NM is null then '' else POPN_NM end,'","',
case when INSRT_DT is null then '' else INSRT_DT end,'","',
case when INSRT_USER_ID is null then '' else INSRT_USER_ID end,'","',
case when UPD_DT is null then '' else UPD_DT end,'","',
case when UPD_USER_ID is null then '' else UPD_USER_ID end,'");') 
from se_popn;
EOF
```